# pyspark zipWithIndex() giving different result in multiple runs in 2 node cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using two node cluster,I have dataframe like below.

```
+----------+------------+
|user_code |productId   |
+----------+------------+
|     1    |          10|
|     2    |          11| 
|     3    |          12| 
|     4    |          13| 
|     5    |          14|
|     6    |          15| 
|     7    |          16|
+----------+------------+
```

above dataframe  I am performing zipWithIndex() for usecase purpose.using below code.

```
users = df_transac.select(user_code).orderBy(user_code).distinct().rdd.map(lambda x: x[0]).zipWithIndex().toDF([user_code, 'user_id'])
items = df_transac.select(item_code).orderBy(item_code).distinct().rdd.map(lambda x:x[0]).zipWithIndex().toDF([item_code, 'item_id'])
```

In first run I am getting result like below.

```
+----------+------------+
|user_code |  user_id   |
+----------+------------+
|     1    |          1 |
|     2    |          2 | 
|     3    |          4 | 
|     4    |          5 | 
|     5    |          3 |
|     6    |          6 | 
|     7    |          7 |
+----------+------------+

in 2nd run(next run time i am getting result like below)
+----------+------------+
|user_code |  user_id   |
+----------+------------+
|     1    |          1 |
|     2    |          2 | 
|     3    |          3 | 
|     4    |          4 | 
|     5    |          5 |
|     6    |          6 | 
|     7    |          7 |
+----------+------------+
```

why index number is changing? 1st run and second run? because  of index changing  i am getting different result in different runs.
in single node cluster it is working as expected.but multi node cluster it is giving wrong result.

how to avoid this i.e. I want to do zipWithIndex() but i should get same index in single node cluster and multi node cluster.is there any alternative for this?

expected output:

```
 +----------+------------+
    |user_code |  user_id   |
    +----------+------------+
    |     1    |          1 |
    |     2    |          2 | 
    |     3    |          3 | 
    |     4    |          4 | 
    |     5    |          5 |
    |     6    |          6 | 
    |     7    |          7 |
    +----------+------------+
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation:

> Note that some RDDs, such as those returned by groupBy(), do not
>   guarantee order of elements in a partition. The index assigned to each
>   element is therefore not guaranteed, and may even change if the RDD is
>   reevaluated. If a fixed ordering is required to guarantee the same
>   index assignments, you should sort the RDD with sortByKey() or save it
>   to a file.

You perform ordering, but later down the line you perform distinct which most likely mess up order. Try to swap those two instructions or use additional `sortByKey()` as advised in doc.